# Creating an instance of shared_ptr<std::thread> with make_shared<std::thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, stdthread

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
    ....
    shared_ptr<std::thread> mThread;
    void Step();
    void LaunchTrhead();
}

void A::LaunchThread()
{
    ...
    mThread=make_shared<std::thread>(Step); // This line gives an error
    ...
}

void A::Step()
{
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to initialise the shared pointer *mThread* so that it calls the function *Step*. However, the compiler gives me the error "*invalid initialization of reference of type ... from expression of type 'unresolved overloaded function type'*". Obviously I'm doing something stupid, but I can't put my finger on it. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Step()` is a non-static member function, so it has an implicit first parameter of type `A*`. You need to bind the current instance of `A` when invoking it.

```
mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::bind(&A::Step, this));
```

You can also use a lambda instead of `bind`

```
mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>([this]{ Step(); });
```

As @Casey points out in the comments, [`std::thread`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) has special treatment for pointer to member functions, and will assume the first following argument is a pointer or reference to the instance on which to call the member function. This means you can avoid `bind` and directly pass `this` as the second argument.

```
mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&A::Step, this);
```

Comment: On the spot! The compiler was telling me ("unresolved function"), but I just couldn't see it, I was completely blinded (I should go home...). Also, in line with what you pointed out, I could declare *Test* static. But your solution is more practical in my case, because it avoids having to pass a pointer to the owner object. Thank you!

Comment: You can pass a pointer-to-member and pointer-to-object directly to the `std::thread` constructor (and `std::bind`, and `std::async`): `mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&A::Step, this);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Casey, that's an even more elegant solution :)

Comment: @Casey How do we pass functional with 1 or more arguments? Suppose the function step had a "function pointer" as an argument then what would be the syntax?

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal Pass the additional arguments to `thread`'s constructor (or `make_shared` in the example above)

Answer (score 1):

Try (use labda instead of the free function):

```
mThread=make_shared<std::thread>([this](){ Step(); });
```

The way it is, you're not passing a reference to this to the constructor inspite of it being a member function.

This solution uses a lambda to create a function-object that takes no parameters but has a reference to this.

If you want to use the global function do this instead, and move `void Step()` to before it's usage:

```
mThread=make_shared<std::thread>(::Step());
```

the `::` removes the ambiguity over the scope of the function.

Comment: ::Step() doesn;t work, sorry. The lambda solution does. Thanks!

Comment: Step() is a member function, only that I forgot to include A:: in its declaration. Now it's edited. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `shared_from_this()` replace this

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of your suggestion?